# xml parsing with php. Best way to get defaults from schema

Tags: php, xsd, simplexml

I have a PHP script that parses xml into an object hierarchy thing through use of simplexml. I started writing the script on the assumption that simplexml could validate against schemas and since the outset it has become quite involved (I should have checked beforehand, dammit). I know I can validate against a schema using DOMDocument::schemaValidate, but I need to grab the default values from the schema for use in my object hierarchy. Is there any way to do this with simplexml? The only thing I can think of is parsing the schma and reading all the 'default' attributes but that seems very much like a horrible horrible hack.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you describe is the only way. There is no way to do marshalling or automatic mapping of schema values to objects. You have to do it manually.